# Security of python flask REST API using HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: python, http, https, flask, basic-authentication

I have python flask running on my server exposing a REST API that is being consumed by an iOS app. I'm using HTTP Basic Authentication using the Flask-HTTPAuth: module. I wanted to know how secure this is because the username:password string would be sent on every request.

Do I need to use HTTPS instead?

Thanks!

Sorry for bad english. Still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current system is (very!) insecure, the login information can be seen during transit by anyone.

The easiest way to add secure HTTP is to install a proxy server like nginx. Then nginx is configured for secure HTTP, but it relays all the requests to the Flask application listening on a private socket without encryption.

[This link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) will send you to the nginx documentation on secure HTTP.

Comment: Thanks - I presumed so.

Do you know of any web tutorial that could help walk me through that process of setting up certificates etc.

I'll start reading up on the basis of HTTPS and also use the link you provided. - thanks

Comment: @wholly_cow: You should be able to find tutorials on how to set up certificates very easily. Hint: use the search term "SSL certificates".

Comment: Thanks @MarkHildreth. That was actually helpful.

I found this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/) that helped the server side and now I'm working through the client side. I had one more question: Given my basic understand of SSL Cert I do not need a signed certificate - is that a correct assumption?
Would my traffic between client and server still be encrypted without a signed cert?

Comment: @Miguel. Using [this method](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/) can I then just use nginx to deploy the flask server in production env?

Comment: @wholly_cow: Please stop asking questions in the comment section of an answer. If you have additional questions, ask it as a new question (or better yet, search for someone else who has asked the same question before).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can have [HTTPS running directly from Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/).  The link has clear instructions of how to do this.  It is a quick, easy method to use while developing.

For production, I'd use Apache's mod_ssl function, or as already stated by Miguel, nginx, as proxy servers.